# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I got below error

> javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to
>   TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1405)
>     at
>
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1381)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:542)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   com.demo.AdminValidator.constraintViolationsForConnMapping(AdminValidator.java:75)
>     at
>   com.demo.utils.tests.AdminValidatorTest.test1ConnectionIdIsRequired(AdminValidatorTest.java:121)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.dem.model.DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK.hashCode(DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.buildHashCode(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:153)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:41)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1396

Here is my code
----------------------- Junit -----------
//DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK Initalization done in construtor

```
@Test
    public void test1ConnectionIdIsRequired() 
    {

        connectionMappingPK.setConnectionId(null);      
        List<String> errorMessages=null;                
        errorMessages=adminValidator.constraintViolationsForDeploymentConfigMapping(connectionMappingPK);

        Assert.assertTrue(errorMessages.contains("ConnectionId must be specified."));
    }
```

---

### DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.demo.DBConstants;

@Embeddable
public class DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JoinColumn(name = DBConstants.CONNECTION_ID, nullable = false)
    @Column(name = DBConstants.CONNECTION_ID, nullable = false, length = 255)   
    @NotNull(message="ConnectionId must be specified.")
    @Size(min=1, max=255)
    private String connectionId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = DBConstants.APPLICATION_ID, length = 255)
    @NotNull(message="ApplicationId must be specified.")
    @Size(min=1, max=255)
    private String applicationId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = DBConstants.APPLICATION_VERSION, length = 10)
    @NotNull(message="ApplicationVersion must be specified.")
    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    private String applicationVersion;

    public String getConnectionId() {
        return connectionId;
    }

    public void setConnectionId(String connectionId) {
        this.connectionId = connectionId;
    }

    public String getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public String getApplicationVersion() {
        return applicationVersion;
    }

    public void setApplicationVersion(String applicationVersion) {
        this.applicationVersion = applicationVersion;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof ConnectionMappingPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        ConnectionMappingPK castOther = (ConnectionMappingPK) other;
        return this.connectionId.equals(castOther.getConnectionId())
                && this.applicationId.equals(castOther.getApplicationId())
                && this.applicationVersion.equals(castOther
                        .getApplicationVersion());

    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.connectionId.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.applicationVersion.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.applicationId.hashCode();
        return hash;

    }

}
```

-----------------------------------------AdminValidator---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import com.Demo.persistence.model.DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK ;

public class AdminValidator {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AdminValidator.class);
    private ValidatorFactory factory = null;
    private Validator validator = null;

    public AdminValidator() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            validator = factory.getValidator();
        }
    }




    public List<String> constraintViolationsForDeploymentConfigMapping(DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK connMapPK) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("In handler #constraintViolationsDetectedForConnMapping of AdminValidator");
        }
        List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
        **Set<ConstraintViolation<DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK>> constraintViolations = validator**
                .validate(connMapPK);
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0)
        {
            Iterator<ConstraintViolation<DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK>> iterator = constraintViolations
                    .iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
           {
                ConstraintViolation<DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK> cv = iterator
                        .next();

                errorMessages.add(cv.getMessage());
            }

        } 
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

---

----------------Persistence .xml --------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="com.Demo.persistence" 
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>       
        <class>com.Demo.persistence.model.DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

we are using eclipselink ,springframework in our demo project, We are not using Spring MVC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be related to bug [HV-1013](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1013), fixed in hibernate 5.3.0.CR1.

Answer (score 20):

The stack trace shows your hashcode method is throwing an NPE :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.dem.model.DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK.hashCode(DeploymentConfigurationMappingPK.java:79) at
```

You need to fix your hashCode method to handle the null.

Comment: Good point, I also had same problem yesterday, by looking to logs I found problem in hashcode implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this issue in Websphere 8.5. Follow this if you already have entityManager instance. I had to use JPA 2.1 hence enabled `Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)`
as shown here - [Class Loader Setting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html)

My Setup -

`Java 7`

`Hibernate Core : 5.1.17.Final`

`Hibernate-validator : 4.2.0.Final`

1. Creating a custom `TraversableResolver`

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/abitgen/21bc364944cb52c23b2dfbba9e137133.js"></script>
```

2. Creating a `Validator` object with the above `TraversableResolver`, here I am returning a String of the ConstraintViolation.

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/abitgen/a0c248e68c5b2180ebbc70c1450d10a5.js"></script>
```

3. To validate any entity, call `validateEntity` method.

Here's my pom.xml

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <org.hibernate.core>5.1.17.Final</org.hibernate.core>
    <org.hibernate.validator>4.2.0.Final</org.hibernate.validator>

    </properties>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.core}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.validator}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.validator}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hibernate.core}</version>
    </dependency>
```