# Configure Hibernate Validator not to use hashCode()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashcode, hibernate-validator

I have the following objects that model requests to my application:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UserRequest {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;

    @Valid
    private AddressRequest address;

}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class AddressRequest {

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String street;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String postcode;

    @NotNull
    private String country;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        AddressRequest that = (AddressRequest) o;

        if (street != null ? !street.equals(that.street) : that.street != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (postcode != null ? !postcode.equals(that.postcode) : that.postcode != null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (country != that.country) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = street != null ? street.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (postcode != null ? postcode.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + country.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, when a client sends a request with null `country` inside the `address` object, validation triggers, but a NPE is thrown in my `hashCode()`. This is very easy to fix on my side, just checking for null country as for the other fields. However, I'd prefer to avoid this. First, this happen to a bunch of classes, not just this one. Then, I don't like checking for null values, specially when I know it shouldn't be null. It'd never be null in my code, I would be having to modify my code because of an external tool.

I use Hibernate Validator 5.2. Is there any way of configuring it to avoid this?

This is the stack trace from the NPE:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1531) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:584) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:490) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:454) 
    ...
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.dto.AddressRequest.hashCode(AddressRequest.java:106) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.buildHashCode(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:143) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.<init>(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:104) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation$TraversableHolder.<init>(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:86) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:31) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1522) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If country is mandatory and you get null values an NPE is the correct reaction. Otherwise your country is not mandatory and then it should't be used in the hash method at all.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace? Might be handy to see where the NPE is triggered. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Added

Comment: Here is workaround for HibernateValidator 4.2.0, I had Websphere 8.5 Application Server https://stackoverflow.com/a/59514454/3333878

Answer (score 1):

So this issue has been fixed as part of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1013 .

Can you upgrade HV to the latest stable e.g. 5.4.1.Final?

It should be a drop-in replacement (see the migration guide here: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateValidatorMigrationGuide ).

Ping me here if you have any issue upgrading.

Comment: @nprensen did it fix your issue?